# If value coming back as infinity default it to 0 - SQL Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I'm creating a SQL report and one of the columns is a calculation that works out the number of pallets of stock.

The issue is some of the fields may be set to 0 which is giving me divide by 0 errors and giving a result of Infinity. I'm wanting to sum up the rows that do have resulting values but the infinity values stop this from being possible.

How can I default the value to 0 if the result from the calculation isn't a value?

My expression is below:

```
=CDBL((Fields!AVAIL.Value/Fields!pack.Value)/Fields!units.Value)
```

Comment: what do Fields!AVAIL.Value, Fields!pack.Value, Fields!units.Value represent in the real world? I'm not sure why you would need to do a division to work out stock

Comment: AVAIL is current qty of stock, pack is the outer pack size, and units is the amount of packs that fit on a pallet. So the calculation gives me the Available stock in terms of pallets.

Comment: OK That makes sense. So you want to show '0' if there is only a partial pallet left?

Comment: Sometimes we don't have the outer pack size, or the amount of packs on a pallet value yet. So they are set at 0. This is giving a result of infinity due to the divide by 0 error. If this is the case I want the value to just be set at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. We basically only do the calculation if both fields are not set to 0

```
=Iif(Fields!pack.Value = 0 Or Fields!units.Value = 0,0,CDBL((Fields!AVAIL.Value/Fields!pack.Value)/Fields!units.Value))
```

Comment: Finally managed to test this - had another bug with my report that I needed to fix first. Works perfectly thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I like to add bespoke code to my reports, using this below will simplify the formulas.

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double) 
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0 
Return 0
Else Return Dividend/Divisor 
End If 
End Function
```

Your formula (which removes the #Infinity and #Div/0 errors) would then become

```
=Code.Divider((Fields!AVAIL.Value,Fields!pack.Value),Fields!units.Value)
```

Comment: This is cool, I've never really thought about adding functions like that into a report. Will definitely have a go at using something like this moving forward. This will be good on large reports as it saves repeating code.